# Is there a way to make a usb NIC show up in the wifi dropdown on a Macbook Pro 15?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, usb, network-adapter

I purchased a USB NIC (Alfa AWUS036AC) because the onboard NIC on my 2014 MBP 15 and my Netgear router don't play nice with each other. Is there a way I can make the networks it (the new NIC) sees appear in my dropdown menu at the top of the screen? The NIC has its own network utility, but it is not as complete as the dropdown at the top of my Mac I am most interested in seeing the advanced setting (when you hold down alt and click). If it involves terminal commands, I am comfortable in the terminal, but would also like the command to change it back. The USB NIC is interface en5. I would also like it to work for wireless diagnostics, if at all possible.